# How can I determine which tasks/programs are running during idle?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm running Windows 7 and I see lots of activity when the machine is idle. How can I filter or view the tasks that are running when idle?

Comment: When you say you 'see lots of activity', where are you looking?

Comment: Lots of HDD activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: open the task manager `(CTRL+ALT+DELETE -> Start Task Manager)` or `(Right-click taskbar -> Start Task Manager)`, click the processes tab, if you have admin privileges then click *Show processes from all users* at the bottom, and then just wait a few minutes (for the pc to go idle) and see which process takes up more CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Type  resmon   in the "search programs and files" box and hit enter, its better than task manager.

.

Answer (score 0):

Use [What's my computer doing](http://www.itsth.com/en/produkte/Whats-my-computer-doing.php). It shows all programs (with details), that are accessing your hard disk or using the CPU. It's freeware.